# I am joining 12 tables on SQL by using Union ALL and receive a column invalid error

Tags: sql, union

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cyclistic
CREATE TABLE Cyclistic
(ride_id nvarchar(255), 
rideable_type nvarchar(255),
Ride_length timestamp,
Day_of_week float, 
start_station_name nvarchar(255),
end_station_name nvarchar(255),
member_casual nvarchar(255)
);

SELECT *
FROM Cyclistic
INSERT INTO Cyclistic 

SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Sep22
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Aug22
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Jul22
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Jun22
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.May22
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Apr22
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Mar22
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Feb22
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Dec21
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Nov21
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Oct21
UNION ALL
SELECT ride_id, rideable_type,Ride_length,[Day of the week], start_station_name,end_station_name,member_casual
FROM dbo.Sep21
```

I am trying to join 12 such tables to get 1 file for analysis. The first table works fine but the for the rest I keep getting column invalid error.

Both tables have the same data type. I am new to SQL self-learning.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual error message and the table definitions for the first two tables

Comment: _"getting column invalid error"_ Perhaps you can copy and paste the exact error/exception message? (`Ctrl+C` would work with standard MessageBoxes too)

Comment: Try the SELECTs for each table individually and check 1) do all tables really have those columns? 2) do the column data types match with the Cyclistic table?

Comment: Are you sure you need `[Day of week]` and not `\`Day of week\`` ? Please tag your dbms (sql-server, mysql, ...)